# Ansible Bastion host connection

Tags: ansible, jumphost

I am trying to SSH hosts through Jump server in Ansible
Do we have an option to use username/password in

```
ansible_ssh_common_args
```

I have tried with SSH keys which is having some problem . Want to try with username and password

Comment: See duplicate: using an ssh key is THE solution (and ["... having some problem" is not an accurate description of your issue](https://idownvotedbecau.se/itsnotworking/))